# JQuery Contains vs Equals

Tags: jquery, html, forms, equals, contains

I have a form and I need help to modify this statement to be equals, not contains:

```
$('<h2>Basic Information</h2>').insertBefore($('h3:contains("Field1")').parent().parent());
```

Thanks as always-

Comment: There is no `equals` selector in jquery. You need to iterate through every h3 element in the document and see if its text equals "Field1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the `h3` that has exactly that text you can use a jquery [filter function.](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) 
Basically you search through all `h3` and find just the ones that have just that word as their text. Also use [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) so you clear the white spaces

Here are 2 solutions.

you can add your other .parent() ) selectors. ALso there could be a more elegant solution to select it's parent. But without knowing your HTML i cannot help you with that. Share your HTML if you need further assistance

```js
$('<h2>Basic Information</h2>').insertBefore($("h3")
  .filter((i, heading) => $(heading).text().trim() === "Field1"))


// on multiple lines

// var heading = $("h3")
//  .filter((i, heading) => $(heading).text().trim() === "Field1")
// $('<h2>Basic Information</h2>').insertBefore($(heading))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  Field1
</h3>
<h3>
  Field1 2
</h3>
<h3>
  Field1
</h3>
```